# Prove holomorphism of expression

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have to prove that given $\gamma$ contour of $G \subset \mathbb{C}$  and $f$ continuous function on $G$.
Then the function $g(z) = \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} - \bar{G}$

My attempt:

I started by using that given any parametrization $\alpha :[a,b] \rightarrow \gamma$ we can rewrite $g(z)$ as:

$g(z) = \int_a^b \frac{f(\alpha(t))}{\alpha(t)-z}\alpha'(t)dt$

Now using the fundamental theorem I derivate to see where $g'(z)$ is defined and I get:

$g'(z) = \frac{f(\alpha(b))}{\alpha(b)-z}\alpha'(b) - \frac{f(\alpha(a))}{\alpha(a)-z}\alpha'(a) $

Here I get stuck, I fail so see how this links back to $g$ being holomorphic at $\mathbb{C} - \bar{G}$.

Any hints on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: The result about the derivative of an integral that you stated is true if the variable of derivation is the upper-bound of the integral, which is not the case here.

Comment: true I don' t know how I missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference quotient can be computed via
$$
g(z_2) - g(z_1) = 
\int_\gamma \left(\frac{1}{w-z_2} - \frac{1}{w-z_1} \right) f(w)\, dw \\
= (z_2 - z_1) \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{(w-z_2)(w-z_1)} \, dw \, .
$$
Now show that the integral has a limit for $z_2 \to z_1$. Conclude that $g$ is differentiable in $\Bbb C \setminus \overline G$, and
$$
 g'(z) = \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^2} \, dw \, .
$$

Comment: thanks! just one question, when you conclude that g is differentiable in $\mathbb{C} - \overline{G}$ can you explain the reasoning for leaving out $\overline{G}$ from the differentiability region, thanks again!

Comment: @DanielBrito: That's how you stated the problem. It would suffice to exclude the image of $\gamma$, where $g$ is not defined.

Comment: perfect now I get it, thank you!

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you show the integral has a limit?

Comment: Might it have to do with taking the limit inside? Seems a little unclear to me

Comment: @someone1: Yes, you can take the limit inside the integral because the integrand is uniformly continuous in $(z,w)$ for $z$ in a neighbourhood of $z_1$ and $w$ on $\gamma$.