# Proof of analyticity of a function on an unit circle .

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Question no. 9[image]

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$  Actually, firstly I was thinking of expanding $\frac{1}{\xi-z}$ but here $1=|\xi|>|z|$ ; so I can't approach .

Then I was trying to use the formula $\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$ alongside the fact that $g$ is continuous on a compact domain .

But, I am getting stuck during the above calculation .

A small hint is warmly appreciated, thanks in advance .

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4117043/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that, when $|\xi|=1$ and $|z|<1$,$$\frac1{\xi-z}=\frac1\xi\frac1{1-z/\xi}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{\xi^{n+1}}.$$Therefore, you have$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{|\xi|=1}\left(\frac{g(\xi)}{\xi^{n+1}}\,\mathrm d\xi\right)z^n.$$